# Center responsive images

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

My images won't center with `margin: 0 auto;` or `padding: 0 auto;`
Also it doesn't work if I do `text-align: center;` in the `<div>` around it.
I think this is because the images are responsive.
So how do I get these images centered?

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1001px) {
  .gallerij {
    max-width: 825px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 0 10px 30px 200px;
  }
}

.gallerij h1 {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.gallerij div.img {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.30);
}

.gallerij div.img:hover {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.gallerij div.img img {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.gallerij div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallerij * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.responsive {
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 24.9999%;
  max-width: 200px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 49.99999%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.gallerij .clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallerij">
  <h1 class="page-titel">All articles:</h1><br>
  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/ERD_Easy/img2.jpg" alt="" class="article-img">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Artikel naam + kleine bescrijving</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/ERD_Easy/img4.jpg" alt="" class="article-img">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Artikel naam + kleine bescrijving</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/ERD_Easy/img3.jpg" alt="" class="article-img">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Artikel naam + kleine bescrijving</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/ERD_Easy/img3.jpg" alt="" class="article-img">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Artikel naam + kleine bescrijving</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/ERD_Easy/img3.jpg" alt="" class="article-img">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Artikel naam + kleine bescrijving</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/ERD_Easy/img3.jpg" alt="" class="article-img">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Artikel naam + kleine bescrijving</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/ERD_Easy/img3.jpg" alt="" class="article-img">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Artikel naam + kleine bescrijving</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/ERD_Easy/img3.jpg" alt="" class="article-img">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Artikel naam + kleine bescrijving</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

The HTML looks that long because I had to do more images so you could see what I mean. When you click on "full page" their will be 4 images next to eachother, in this little one (probably) 3 and I dont know if you can make it smaller but then it will go to 2 images and finally 1.
When it's 3 and 4 it is centered but when it's at 2 or 1 it will not be centered anymore. Idk if you can see it not getting centered at the snippet so I will paste some print screens to show it.

**2 images next to eachother:**
[image: 2 images next to eachother]

**1 image:**
[image: 1 image]

The only problem is that they are not centered and I can't find how to do that.

**Do you need more code or information?**

Comment: if you want to center an image with `margin: 0 auto;` you need to supply a width, not `auto`

Comment: Set float to none.  Make sure images are display: block also. (which they should be naturally.)

Comment: Why does .responsive have a max-width of 200px? This is not overridden anywhere, this might be your problem? The only thing you override is width in your media queries.

Comment: The max-width only happens when the 24.999% or the 49.999% are bigger then 200px, And the pictures don't look good when they have a width more then 200px so thats why I added that.

Comment: Did you change anything else? Your code snippet works completely as expected with the changes recommended.

Comment: Ye I see I deleted the max-width: 825px; when I experimented myself :) ups.. your answer worked thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your images in an overarching div, and center that with [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).

Alternatively, remove the `float:left` from your items, make them `display:inline-block`, and wrap them in a div with `text-align:center`.

Flexbox example:

```
<div style="
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
">
    <div class="responsive">
        <div class="img">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="img/ERD_Easy/img2.jpg" alt="" class="article-img">
            </a>
            <div class="desc">Artikel naam + kleine bescrijving</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Without flexbox solution:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <div class="responsive" style="float:none;display:inline-block;">
        <div class="img">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="img/ERD_Easy/img2.jpg" alt="" class="article-img">
            </a>
            <div class="desc">Artikel naam + kleine bescrijving</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't use any fletbox in my site. So can I just add 1 thing with fletbox? I thought you have to make your entire website fletbox then.

Comment: No you don't, I've also added a non-flexbox option if you don't want to use it.

Comment: I thought this was the answer, but when I make my web page big again it won't use my width I gave it anymore. I am going to add print screen to my question

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking this might be what you want?
Make sure that you remove the float in order to reset the images from floating to the left.
Also added a margin: 0 auto;
(Or text-align center on the image container) However you want to do that piece.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1001px) {
  .gallerij {
    max-width: 825px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 0 10px 30px 200px;
  }
}

.gallerij h1 {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.gallerij div.img {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.30);
}

.gallerij div.img:hover {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.gallerij div.img img {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.gallerij div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallerij * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.responsive {
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 24.9999%;
  max-width: 200px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 49.99999%;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.gallerij .clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallerij">
  <h1 class="page-titel">All articles:</h1><br>
  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/ERD_Easy/img2.jpg" alt="" class="article-img">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Artikel naam + kleine bescrijving</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/ERD_Easy/img4.jpg" alt="" class="article-img">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Artikel naam + kleine bescrijving</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/ERD_Easy/img3.jpg" alt="" class="article-img">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Artikel naam + kleine bescrijving</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/ERD_Easy/img3.jpg" alt="" class="article-img">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Artikel naam + kleine bescrijving</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/ERD_Easy/img3.jpg" alt="" class="article-img">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Artikel naam + kleine bescrijving</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/ERD_Easy/img3.jpg" alt="" class="article-img">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Artikel naam + kleine bescrijving</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/ERD_Easy/img3.jpg" alt="" class="article-img">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Artikel naam + kleine bescrijving</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="responsive">
    <div class="img">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="img/ERD_Easy/img3.jpg" alt="" class="article-img">
      </a>
      <div class="desc">Artikel naam + kleine bescrijving</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked but someone else just had the same answer as you posted

Comment: I know, I watched him edit his post after my comments on your original post above lol.
All that matters is that you got it to work and glad you ultimately came to a good conclusion.

Comment: I thought I got it worked but a new problem seems to happen.

Comment: Ah, Ye it works again. I accidantly removed the max-width myself but got it working again. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
.gallerij {
    width: 420px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I can't give it a standard with. I want it to be 100% of the screen with a max-width of 825px but if I make it 
`.gallerij {
    width: 100%;
max-width: 825px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}`